# ¿Se puede crear un boton para descargar 2 archivos?

Tags: html

Quiero crear un botón de descarga cuando se presione se descarguen 2 cosas. En vez de 1.
Solo en html, ya que estoy muy limitado por wordpress.
Igual pienso que no se puede, pero aun tengo esperanza.

Comment: Utlizando únicamente _html_ no se puede, lo mejor que podrías hacer es crear un _.zip_ con los dos archivos. Con Javascript lo podrías hacer, siempre que wordpress te lo permita.

Comment: El problema es que los archivos estan almacenados ya. Pero gracias de todos modos.

Comment: Hola Jenio158, ¿resolviste el problema al final? Se me ocurren algunas soluciones, pero o bien haría falta JavaScript, o algo de código en el lado del servidor.